# Opera is not triggering Wand to save password

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm completely cluesless with that one:
On http://wurzelimperium.de Opera stopped saving passwords via Wand. It's just not triggered anymore. i've tried changing the form by providing a real "submit" inputfield that should be activated via javascript. this doesn't help, any ideas?

Comment: It’d be cool if you updated the question with a piece of code with the password field.

Answer (score 4):

You have quite a strange markup inside:

```
<td class="brownbold">Passwort</td>
<td><input type="Password" class="text loginput" style="width:100%;" id="login_pass" maxlength="100" size="15" tabindex="3">
<input type="hidden" name="pass" value="" id="b64_pass"></td>
```

Why would you need a second hidden field? Why doesn’t the first one have a `name`?

Start with lowercasing the word "password" (in `type`) and adding a `name` to the first input.

Comment: jesus christ, you saved my day! the missing name attribute did the trick!
the password is encoded to base64 with javascript, that's why the second input field is there. and the 'Password' was a typo. thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

You can really, really close it now at least....since the wand is triggered (and I am suddenly a registered user of what seems to be a game regarding german garden gnomes ;-)